# Liquibase add comment to table

Tags: liquibase

I'm currently trying to add comment on tables in liquibase 3.1.1

What I want to do is `ALTER TABLE t1 COMMENT = 'New table comment';`

I didn't find any help in the documentation of liquibase about this case, there is only help for adding comments on columns.

I am currently thinking of creating a customChange or doing the change by myself with SQL statements but as we are going to migrate from MySQL to Oracle I would like to avoid this solution (or use it in last resort).

Has anyone found another solution for this problem ?

Comment: You can define table comments using the `remarks` attribute in the `createTable` tag. But I am not aware of an `alterTable` that could be used (and in Oracle it would be `comment on table is '...'` not an alter table)

Comment: That's what I feared..... Thank you :)

Comment: Any news about how to change a table comment ?

Comment: @RegRog Sadly no news about that. I am not using Liquibase anymore but I'm keeping this thread open in case someone finds a solution for this.

Comment: Are you using something different than liquibase?

Comment: I am in another company than the one I asked this question for. I do not use liquibase or any technologies of the same kind at the moment.

Comment: You can use the ChangeSet `setColumnRemarks`, check if it is supported by your database [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/set_column_remarks.html). I hope you find it useful

Answer (score 2):

`COMMENT ON TABLE` is absolutely helpful in this case. See example I provided below along with some tips and pitfalls about editing tables using liqubase.

Continuing the response above, I'd like to pay attention on tag `<preConditions>` here. It's critical when dealing with tables to ask liqubase whether the certain table exists at the moment you try to edit one. Here's some example of this behavior:

```
<changeSet id="your_table_id" author="author_name" dbms="postgresql">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <tableExists tableName="table_name" schemaName="schema_name"/>
        </preConditions>
        <sql>
            COMMENT ON TABLE schema_name.table_name is 'YOUR_COMMENT_ON_TABLE';
        </sql>
 </changeSet>
```

In case dealing with columns (editing, adding, deleting) ALSO consider asking liqubase the similar way of the existing or absence of the specific column(s):

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <not>
         <columnExists tableName="table_name" schemaName="schema_name" 
             columnName="column_name"/>
    </not>
</preConditions>
<sql>
...
</sql>
```

The example above checks if column NOT present in table and then executes some SQL script.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating a custom SQL statement with a `<sql>` tag (or `"sql"` key if you are using JSON) in the `changeSet` (documentation can be found [here](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html)).

Since I am using PostgreSQL, the SQL syntax for adding a comment to a table is `COMMENT ON TABLE table_name IS 'text'`. Below is the entire `changeSet` in XML format:

```
<changeSet author="gfigueroa" id="add-comment-to-table-xyz">
    <sql dbms="postgresql"
         endDelimiter=";"
         splitStatements="true"
         stripComments="true">
        COMMENT ON TABLE xyz IS 'This is a test comment';
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is a solution meanwhile (2023):

```
<changeSet>  
  <setTableRemarks  
    remarks="A String"  
    tableName="person"
  />  
</changeSet>
```

See the [liquibase documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/set-table-remarks.html) for details and other formats.

Worked on my machine against an Oracle DB.